# Generic ToType() extension - is there a better way?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, extension-methods

The following works, the test passes.  But I'm unhappy with having to explicitly pass the assembly name in the call.  Is there a better way?

```
public static object ToType<T>(this object obj, T type, string assembly, IDictionary<string,string> maps) {
    //create instance of T type object:
    var tmp = Activator.CreateInstance(assembly, type.ToString()); 

    foreach( var map in maps) {
        try 
        {   
            PropertyInfo source = obj.GetType()
                .GetProperty(map.Value);

            tmp.Unwrap().GetType().GetProperty(map.Key)
                .SetValue(tmp.Unwrap(), source.GetValue(obj, null), null);
        }
        catch 
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Error converting to Type: "+type);
        }
    }
    return tmp.Unwrap();
}

[Test]
public void TestToTypeExtension()
{
    Source item = new Source();
    item.OtherObj_One     = "1234567890";
    item.OtherObj_Code      = "IBM.N";
    item.OtherObj_CodeType  = "S";
    item.OtherObj_CodeGroup = "EQUITY";

    Target row = (Target)item.ToType(typeof(Target), ((typeof(Target)).Assembly).FullName, Target.map);

    Assert.AreEqual(item.OtherObj_One, row.One);
    Assert.AreEqual(item.OtherObj_Code, row.Code);
    Assert.AreEqual(item.OtherObj_CodeType, row.CodeType);
}

public class Target
{
    public static Dictionary<String, String> map = new Dictionary<string, string>{
                                                    {"One"          ,"OtherObj_One"},
                                                    {"Code"         ,"OtherObj_Code"},
                                                    {"CodeType"     ,"OtherObj_CodeType"},

    };

    public String One { get; set; }
    public String Code { get; set; }
    public String CodeType { get; set; }

}

public class Source
{
    public String OtherObj_One { get; set; }
    public String OtherObj_Code { get; set; }
    public String OtherObj_CodeType { get; set; }
    public String OtherObj_CodeGroup { get; set; }

}
```

**Update:**

The value of `((typeof(T)).Assembly).FullName` executed inside the extension method is: `mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`

If I change the object creation statement to `T tmp = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();` I get the following error:

```
Test Name:  TestToTypeExtension
Test FullName:  Solution.Test.UtilsTests.TestToTypeExtension
Test Source:    [ ... ]\UnitTestProject1\UtilsTests.cs : line 39
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.071

Result Message: System.MissingMethodException : Cannot create an abstract class.
Result StackTrace:  
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance[T]()
at Util.MappingExtensions.ToType[T](Object obj, T type, String assembly, IDictionary`2 maps) in [ ... ]\Utils\MappingExtensions.cs:line 22
at Solution.Test.UtilsTests.TestToTypeExtension() in [ ... ]\UnitTestProject1\UtilsTests.cs:line 46
```

**Update2**

The winning code (including the related List extension) is, thanks to , follows. Btw, the extensions work for anonymous types, such as those returned by linq `select new` expressions (i.e. `select new {prop1 = x, prop2 = y}`) -- which was my principal motivation.

```
    public static object ToType<T>(this object obj, IDictionary<string, string> maps) 
           where T : new()
    {
        T tmp = new T();
        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        Type tType = typeof(T);

        foreach( var map in maps) {
            try 
            {   
                 PropertyInfo source = objType.GetProperty(map.Value);

                 tType.GetProperty(map.Key)
                         .SetValue(tmp, source.GetValue(obj, null), null);
             }
             catch 
             {
                 throw new ArgumentException("Error converting to Type: "+ tType);
             }
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    public static List<T> ToTypeList<T,U>(this List<U> source
                  , IDictionary<string, string> maps) 
        where T : new ()
    { 
        List<T> result = new List<T>();

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            result.Add((T)item.ToType<T>(maps));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what it is you're doing?

Comment: It's a light-weight object to object mapper as a generic object extension - given an object A, and a map of A's property names to B's property names (Dictionary) return a populated instance of type B.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something glaringly obvious, but any reason you aren't using the [`Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) generic overload instead? You can just have at that point `T tmp = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();`, it would be type-safe _without_ casting, and your calling code would be `Target row = item.ToType<Target>(Target.map)`? EDIT: Or if you like (which might be better since it's _already_ generic and requires a parameterless constructor) is to add the `new` constraint. Then it just becomes `T tmp = new T();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [`Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) generic overload and skip the assembly bit. This would also strongly type it:

```
public static object ToType<T>(this object obj, IDictionary<string,string> maps) {
    //create instance of T type object:
    T tmp = Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); 

    foreach( var map in maps) {
        try 
        {   
            PropertyInfo source = obj.GetType()
                .GetProperty(map.Value);

            tmp.Unwrap().GetType().GetProperty(map.Key)
                .SetValue(tmp.Unwrap(), source.GetValue(obj, null), null);
        }
        catch 
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Error converting to Type: "+ typeof(T));
        }
    }

    return tmp.Unwrap();
}
```

In addition, since you're already requiring the types to have a parameterless constructor (via your usage of `Activator.CreateInstance` without parameter arguments), consider using the [`new constraint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sd2w2ew5.aspx) to enforce compile-time safety:

```
public static object ToType<T>(this object obj, IDictionary<string,string> maps) where T : new()
{
    //create instance of T type object:
    T tmp = new T();

    foreach( var map in maps) {
        try 
        {   
            PropertyInfo source = obj.GetType()
                .GetProperty(map.Value);

            tmp.Unwrap().GetType().GetProperty(map.Key)
                .SetValue(tmp.Unwrap(), source.GetValue(obj, null), null);
        }
        catch 
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Error converting to Type: "+ typeof(T));
        }
    }

    return tmp.Unwrap();
}
```

Your usage might then look like this without the need to cast:

```
Target row = item.ToType<Target>(Target.map)
```

---

I'm also not sure what's going on with the `Unwrap()` calls and calling `.GetType()` on them, but I suspect that they're superfluous here, so perhaps your method can be simplified to:

```
public static object ToType<T>(this object obj, IDictionary<string,string> maps) where T : new()
{
    //create instance of T type object:
    T tmp = new T();

    Type objType = obj.GetType();
    Type tType = typeof(T);

    foreach( var map in maps) {
        try 
        {   
            PropertyInfo source = objType.GetProperty(map.Value);

            tType.GetProperty(map.Key)
                .SetValue(tmp, source.GetValue(obj, null), null);
        }
        catch 
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Error converting to Type: "+ tType);
        }
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: That's the only way I could get a working Activator.CreateInstance --- perhaps because the type declaration and the extension live in different assemblies (in my solution)?  I like the improvement the new constraint makes ... I knew there had to be a better way ....

Comment: Regarding the extension method being in a different assembly, I don't think that should matter. When you call it, you're already feeding the resolved type. Does using this overload still not work for you? What exception does it throw?

Comment: What you say here makes sense, but it doesn't work.  I added the exception details as an update on the question.

Comment: Selected your answer.  I would like to understand what was going on without the new constraint -- not enough to make another question  about it -- if it makes sense to you, maybe reply here?

Comment: @marfarma: From the error message, it looks like you were passing in an `abstract` class for the type `T`. But the code you posted does _not_ include any `abstract` classes; did you try to use a different class or was the code you posted incomplete?

Comment: The code is exactly as I had posted - with only the property names in the test case changed to protect the guilty.  I'd love to understand exactly what the problem was, but I don't have time to really dig.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you already have the code you need.  Just move it into the Generic function.

```
var assembly = ((typeof(T)).Assembly).FullName;
```

Comment: Except it doesn't return the right assembly - see update for details.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like is better - it massively simplifies your call:

```
public static T ToType<T>(this object obj, IDictionary<string, string> maps)
{
    //create instance of T type object:
    var tmp = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T).Assembly.FullName, typeof(T).ToString());

    foreach (var map in maps)
    {
        try
        {
            PropertyInfo source = obj.GetType()
                .GetProperty(map.Value);

            tmp.Unwrap().GetType().GetProperty(map.Key)
                .SetValue(tmp.Unwrap(), source.GetValue(obj, null), null);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Error converting to Type: " + typeof(T));
        }
    }
    return (T)tmp.Unwrap();
}
```

Usage:

```
 Target row = item.ToType<Target>(Target.map);
```